# How do you find original classnames for obfuscated(minimized) CSS class names? deobfuscation

Tags: html, css, frontend, deobfuscation

I am trying to learn front web development by dissecting sites.
However, obfuscated class names throw me off.
For example, random class names on https://toss.im/

```
 <div class="_2NL6PWn4PGDiKgUNENyIeH">
          <div class="_1LP0bn60-qJ9tcwOIIU0K0">
            <h1 class="xdkzi6K8CAHBm0bIr7Yac"><br /></h1>
            <div class="AVwdr4xGFNY9h2o0dXQyk"><a
```

I understand obfustication is necessary to minimize loading time, but it's unreadable for someone who wants to learn how the site was built.

Comment: Just from the HTML, it's impossible.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  I have cloned the site using httrack, what type of files or information do I need?